# Как найти Key по Value в Map (Java)?

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Нужно выбрать и вернуть первый попавшийся ключ `key` из `Map` по его значению `value`. Пробую так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
{
    String s = reader.readLine();
    if (result.containsValue(s))
    {
        System.out.println(result.get(i));
        break;
    }
}
```

Возвращает `null`.

Comment: Вы не уточняете экземпляром какого класса является result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ищем ключ по значению

```
HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
Collection<String> collection= map.keySet();

Object desiredObject=new Object();//что хотим найти
for (String key : collection) {
    Object obj = map.get(key);
    if (key != null) {
        if (desiredObject.equals(obj)) {
            return key;// нашли наше значение и возвращаем  ключ
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

как верно заметил [[@jmu](/users/1810/jmu)](/users/1810/jmu)  лучше использовать map.entrySet()

```
HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> entrySet=map.entrySet();

Object desiredObject=new Object();//что хотим найти
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> pair : entrySet) {
    if (desiredObject.equals(pair.getValue())) {
        return pair.getKey();// нашли наше значение и возвращаем  ключ
    }
}
```

Comment: > Нужно вывести значение key из карты по
> найденному значению volue

...

> Спасибо за ответ! Однако он мне не
> совсем подходит. Я с клавиатуры
> постепенно заполняю карту. Потом ввожу
> одно из значений value. Код должен
> вывести ключ на экран


я привёл пример кода (далее доделываете под свои нужды)
в любом случае стоит подумать над тем что и как вы делаете (и вообще зачем для этого использовать мап)

Comment: лучше использовать метод `entrySet()` вместо `keySet()` особенно в данном случае

Comment: да действительно лучше, обновил ответ

Answer (score 8):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
Map<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
Object value = new Object();

Optional<String> result = maps.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> value.equals(entry.getValue()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();

if (result.isPresent())
    System.out.println(result.get());
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) из [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6) (google java libraries).

Тогда будет метод inverse(), после применения которого key(и) станут value(ами), а value(и) - key(ами)

Answer (score 0):

Например (Имя - ключ, Телефон - значение, мы знаем телефон, нужно достать ключ):

```
TreeMap<String, String> phoneBook = new TreeMap<>();
String phone = "7-111-111-11-11";
String Key = "";
            for (String k : phoneBook.keySet())
            {
               if (phoneBook.get(k).equals(phone) )  {
                   Key = k;
                   break;
               }
            }
System.out.println("Ключ: " + Key + " / Значение: " + phoneBook.get(Key));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // ориентируйтесь на [лучшие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa)