# Как найти Key в hashMap по Value(Java), чтобы было как вызов функции?

Tags: java

Прощу объяснить, как в одну строчку и без циклов получить ключ (вместо ???????)?

```
  System.out.println("Wrong answer. The correct one is \"" + backCard[j] + "\"" + ", you've just written the definition of \"" + ????????????? + "\"");
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563654/340492

Comment: спасибо,  а как сделать так, чтобы я обращался как к функции?

Comment: В каком смысле, как к функции? Сделайте как в этом ответе, вызовите стрим, потом все последующие методы, и всё.

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло это

```
public class flashcards {

public static Object getKeyFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
    for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
        if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
            return o;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Так здесь же вы используете цикл! Кстати, здесь у вас может быть `NPE` в `hm.get(o).equals(value)`, если `hm.get(o)` равен `null`.

Comment: потом просто эту функцию можно вызвать getKeyFromValue(yourmap, value) и вернет ключ

Comment: да с циклом, но я просто хотел функцию

Comment: неа, NPE в моей программе не получается

Comment: Это хорошо, но если мапа не хранит значения по ключу `o`, то вернётся `null`.